# Onde guardar a informação?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, firebase

Tenho uma aplicação em angular, básica com formulários que guarda os dados em *arrays* e recebe os `dado in dados` em `div's`. Agora como eu poderei armazenar estes dados? Que opções tenho estando a utilizar **AngularJS**?

Estando familiarizado com php e **MySql**, sei que posso passar os dados por `$http` e chamar o ficheiro `.php` que insere na base de dados relacional, mas também sei que existe o MongoDB... 
Uma aplicação que utiliza **MongoDB** funciona em um servidor **PHP/Linux**?

Mais uma coisa, na página do Angular eles fazem referência ao **Firebase** que me deixou com mais duvidas ainda. Qual a melhor maneira de "jogar" com dados no AngularJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma "melhor" maneira de salvar dados com `AngularJs`, tudo vai depender das suas necessidades/projetos. O `MongoDB` funciona sim em servidores Linux e para utiliza-lo com php é necessário instalar um [driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/)

Já o `FireBase` é um serviço `BaaS`*(Backend as a Service)* que já fornece a maioria das funcionalidades que você teria que implementar em um Backend. Dessa forma você irá fazer a conexão direto com o serviço.

Referências:

[Utilizando a dupla MongoDB e PHP](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-a-dupla-mongodb-e-php/27798)

[BaaS - Backend as a Service](http://italoqueiroz.github.io/blog/2013/07/15/baas-backend-as-a-service/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Depende de como você deseja modelar sua aplicação:

- **No seu browser** - Você pode escrever uma solução completamente client-side, mantendo os dados do usuário na instância do *browser*. Para tanto, utilize a [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) ou uma biblioteca que lide com ela, como a [angular-webstorage](https://github.com/fredricrylander/angular-webstorage). A desvantagem é que seus dados persistirão apenas para aquele browser.
- **Em um servidor** - Você precisará de um back-end para armazenar seus dados. Modelos variam: Desde uma implementação `NodeJS + object-storage` para aplicações simples, passando por bancos de dados relacionais ([MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/), [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/), [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html), MS SQL Server e outros) ou não ([MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), [Redis](http://redis.io/), [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), etc).